# Android: Displaying a PDF inside android application

Tags: android, webview

In the application I receive a PDF from an API call so it is inside a byte array and I would like to display it inside the application without having to save it in the user's phone. I have tried a WebView but it has not worked. Seems like a WebView will display a PDF from an url but will not render it if you give it the PDF as a string.

I was wondering if there was a way to display a PDF inside an android application without having to save it in the user's phone?

Comment: Have you tried putting the bytes in a BufferedInputStream creating a tmp file and feeding the file to the webview? Or also create the file and do an Intent Actio.View

Comment: "I was wondering if there was a way to display a PDF inside an android application without having to save it in the user's phone" -- most PDF rendering options require a file, mainly because they are aimed at displaying PDFs that may be too big to hold in memory. "Seems like a webview will display a pdf from a url but will not render it if you give it the pdf as a string" -- `WebView` has no built-in ability to render a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this by writing the received bytes of the pdf file to a temporary cache DIR and then open it with an intent. So for example in an async task I download the file in the `doInBackground` method and do this in the `onPostExecute`.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {
    final File reportFile = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "pdf-file.pdf");

    final BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(reportFile));
    output.write(result);
    output.close();

    Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),  BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID  + ".fileprovider", reportFile);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is working quite well. The only thing you have to do is to check if the user has a PDF reader installed that is working. 
The advantage I see with this solution is that you provide the user the opportunity to further do with the pdf what he or she wants (e.g. print, store, share, ...). If you just display it within a frame in your app you would quite limit the interaction possibilities (or would have to implement them all by your self).

Comment: well it is in the cache directory (you could also store it in the internal cache directory - then you can just access it within your app). But you do not really have to take care of deleting it since android can take care of the cache itself.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a shot!